# Which statistical procedure to use?

Tags: statistics, data-science-model, hypothesis-testing, t-test

I'm new to Hypothesis testing. I can't really think of how to answer this -

Five students take a test one year and another test the next year. Their overall grades(in %) are given below for the test-1 and test-2. Which statistical procedure (e.g. t-test) would be most appropriate to claim that the students overall course grades are similar in both tests? Assume normality requirements hold.

If anyone knows the answer, kindly explain.

Comment: So the question is which statistical procedure to use, but the possible answers are just some numbers?

Comment: yes exactly my confusion. I struggled to understand it too.. @user2974951

Comment: Set aside the multiple guess answers for a moment. How would you approach the problem? When you do it that way, do you get a number near any of the possible answers?

Answer (score 1):

You may apply paired t-test to test your hypothesis:
the students overall course grades are the same in both tests.